# Laravel 5.4 - Laravel Mix ( Webpack ) High Cpu Usage

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, homestead

On Windows hosts using Laravel Homestead, doing `npm run watch-poll` on a fresh Laravel installation will yield high cpu usage. You have to poll because on Windows hosts, webpack doesn't pick up on the changes to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution has been to go into `/node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js` and find the `ignored` option and set it to `/node_modules/`, **without** quote marks. It's not the optimal solution because you lose the ability to pass in the `ignored` option.